# Google's Featured Rich snippets ratings for organisation not being showed on Google Search

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data, homepage

I have added Schema Code (Json Ld) for organisation with ratings, there's **no error** in the Structured data testing tool + it shows correctly in the **preview result**. But even then the Ratings are **not being shown** on Google Search.

[Structured Data Testing Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkBlN.png)

Comment: Sorry but we already have a vast amount of questions and answers regarding review stars not working. While your question doesn't mention review stars on the home page your comment does in one of the answers which indicates your question is actually review stars not working on homepage which again, has been asked in various forms on Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

The first point I would say is that whether the ratings show in SERP results or not very much depends on whether search engines have picked up the schema yet.It takes quite some time. Have you checked Search Console to see if Google is picking this up in the structured data report? Secondly, even if Google is acknowledging the mark up, it may not show the rich snippet at all or for some time. If you have it implemented correctly, it can be a waiting game.

Comment: actually it is working for all other pages, but it isn't working for the home page.

Comment: Yes, I have just seen the comment above. We have a client which sells health products and the ratings never show on the homepage.